How to install one MacOS per disk on Mac mini late 2014? i.e one macOS in the SSD and another macOS in the hard drive?
What I am trying to achieve:
I have a Mac mini late 2014. From the moment I bought it, inside the Mac mini:

there was a 1TB spinning drive, it is a bigger one.
there is a 121Gb SSD, which is smaller and thinner (see photo).


The 1TB spinning hard drive failed, and I replaced it with a SAMSUNG EVO 1TB SSD.
From there, I reinstalled MacOS on the SAMSUNG EVO 1TB SSD.
Now I have a Mac mini late 2014, with a SAMSUNG EVO 1TB, with macOS Monterey.
Somehow, I think the "Fusion Drive" was split, broke, during this process, as I am now able to "see" two disks.


Here is also what I can see from Application -> Disk utility:

This is "fine" as I now have a SAMSUNG EVO 1TB, it is fast enough that I do not really need the 121Gb SSD as Fusion Drive.
My question is more about: I am using the macOS Monterey quite fine.
But is it possible to install another macOS Monterey on the 121Gb SSD? And dual boot from between them?
Meaning, for instance, user1, me, would use the Mac mini from the SAMSUNG EVO 1TB with its macOS.
While a user2, would use the same Mac mini, with hopefully also a Moneterey, but booting from the 121Gb SSD?
What I am hoping for is to avoid creating two users within the SAMSUNG EVO 1TB, or a dual boot within the SAMSUNG EVO 1TB.
(Not partitioning my 1TB SAMSUNG disk to install two OS in the 1TB SAMSUNG, I would like one OS per disk)
More like each user has its own disk.
How to achieve that?

Hello and welcome to Ask Different. If you open Disk utility (located in Application/Utilities), does it show up as two different disks as well? In that case you should be able to format the smaller disk and install macOS on it. Try the recovery installer from recovery partition.

Yes you can do it, as @iTunes said. You can also potentially partition some of the larger disk for user2 to use for their files and apps, though it's not recommended to store main folders like Desktop, Downloads etc on another disk. Rather you should symlink subfolders and apps on the larger drive to the appropriate places on the system drive. There are guides to symlinking on the web and probably more concise and technical versions in answers here.

@iTunes thanks for the comment, I attached he screenshot of what I see in Application -> Disk utility

@LouieLouie Thanks for the comment, I hope to achieve one OS per disk, and not partition one disk with two OS

@PatPanda I meant you absolutely can install one OS per disk. Then, after doing so, you can take advantage of the extra capacity on the larger disk by making a partition on it to store some of user2’s files.

As @iTunes suggested. For Monterey the smaller disk will need to be formatted as an APFS volume. Start your Mac in Recovery mode (Command+R on startup), select 'Install macOS', select The 128GB disk and it should install. Then continue to create the second user/guest profile. Your second user/guest will have to then select the second Monterey OS using 'option' on startup. This may help explain https://support.apple.com/en-us/118282

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The answer is not complete, but it did help a bit

what more detail do you need ?
